# Cannot send to XA JMS Queue with JmsTemplate

Tags: java, spring-boot, transactions, activemq-classic, xa

My SpringBoot Application reads some data from the database and write these objects to a jms queue.
I use XA for the transaction handling.
But when I would send an object to the queue I got the following Exception:

```
2018-09-13 13:44:46 ERROR c.s.c.m2m.MachineMessageProcessor [] - Processing of messages failed
org.springframework.jms.UncategorizedJmsException: Uncategorized exception occurred during JMS processing; nested exception is com.atomikos.jms.AtomikosTransactionRequiredJMSException: The JMS session you are using requires a JTA transaction context for the calling thread and none was found.
Please correct your code to do one of the following: 
1. start a JTA transaction if you want your JMS operations to be subject to JTA commit/rollback, or
2. increase the maxPoolSize of the AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean to avoid transaction timeout while waiting for a connection, or
3. create a non-transacted session and do session acknowledgment yourself, or
4. set localTransactionMode to true so connection-level commit/rollback are enabled.
at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsUtils.convertJmsAccessException(JmsUtils.java:316)
at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.convertJmsAccessException(JmsAccessor.java:169)
at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:487)
at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.send(JmsTemplate.java:570)
at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.convertAndSend(JmsTemplate.java:696)
at com.schaerer.coffeelink.m2m.MachineStatusReader.processMessages(MachineStatusReader.java:62)
at com.schaerer.coffeelink.m2m.BatchedMessageProcessor.processPage(BatchedMessageProcessor.java:70)
at com.schaerer.coffeelink.m2m.BatchedMessageProcessor.access$000(BatchedMessageProcessor.java:22)
at com.schaerer.coffeelink.m2m.BatchedMessageProcessor$1.doInTransactionWithoutResult(BatchedMessageProcessor.java:57)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionCallbackWithoutResult.doInTransaction(TransactionCallbackWithoutResult.java:34)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133)
at com.schaerer.coffeelink.m2m.MachineMessageProcessor.executeInNewTransaction(MachineMessageProcessor.java:146)
at com.schaerer.coffeelink.m2m.BatchedMessageProcessor.processPageInTransaction(BatchedMessageProcessor.java:53)
at com.schaerer.coffeelink.m2m.BatchedMessageProcessor.execute(BatchedMessageProcessor.java:45)
at com.schaerer.coffeelink.m2m.DataReaderScheduler.runDataReader(DataReaderScheduler.java:31)
at com.schaerer.coffeelink.m2m.DataReaderScheduler$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$56ffc69e.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:720)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:85)
at com.schaerer.coffeelink.common.security.api.authorization.RunAsRoleAspect.aroundwithResourceAccessPermissionAnnotation(RunAsRoleAspect.java:51)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:629)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:618)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:168)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655)
at com.schaerer.coffeelink.m2m.DataReaderScheduler$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a8c5dee8.runDataReader(<generated>)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:65)
at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

The JMS Configuration is the following:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJms
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class JmsConfiguration {

  @Value("${messaging.broker-url}")
  private String brokerUrl;

  @Bean
  public JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> jmsListenerContainerFactory(DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer,
                                                                ConnectionFactory jmsConnectionFactory,
                                                                PlatformTransactionManager platformTransactionManager) {
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    configurer.configure(factory, jmsConnectionFactory);
    factory.setTransactionManager(platformTransactionManager);
    factory.setSessionTransacted(true);
    factory.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.DUPS_OK_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    return factory;
  }

  @Bean
  public ConnectionFactory jmsConnectionFactory() {
    ActiveMQXAConnectionFactory activeMQXAConnectionFactory = new ActiveMQXAConnectionFactory(brokerUrl);
    activeMQXAConnectionFactory.setTrustAllPackages(true);

    AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean atomikosConnectionFactoryBean = new AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean();
    atomikosConnectionFactoryBean.setLocalTransactionMode(false);
    atomikosConnectionFactoryBean.setXaConnectionFactory(activeMQXAConnectionFactory);
    return atomikosConnectionFactoryBean;
  }

  @Bean
  public JmsTemplate JmsTemplate(ConnectionFactory jmsConnectionFactory) {
    JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate();
    jmsTemplate.setConnectionFactory(jmsConnectionFactory);
    jmsTemplate.setSessionTransacted(true);
    return jmsTemplate;
  }

  @Bean
  public PlatformTransactionManager platformTransactionManager(UserTransactionManager atomikosUserTransactionManager,
                                                           UserTransaction atomikosUserTransaction) {
    JtaTransactionManager manager = new JtaTransactionManager();
    manager.setTransactionManager(atomikosUserTransactionManager);
    manager.setUserTransaction(atomikosUserTransaction);
    manager.setAllowCustomIsolationLevels(true);
    return manager;
  }

  @Bean
  UserTransactionManager atomikosUserTransactionManager() {
    UserTransactionManager manager = new UserTransactionManager();
    manager.setStartupTransactionService(true);
    manager.setForceShutdown(false);
    return manager;
  }

  @Bean
  UserTransaction atomikosUserTransaction() {
    return new UserTransactionImp();
  }
}
```

The calling code is:

```
@Transactional
private void processMessages(List<MachineStatus> machineStatuses) {
    if (machineStatuses != null && !machineStatuses.isEmpty()) {
      jmsAdapter.convertAndSend(MACHINE_STATUS_QUEUE, machineStatuses, message -> {
        message.setJMSCorrelationID(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        return message;
      });
      setLastId(machineStatuses.get(machineStatuses.size() - 1).getId());
    }
}
```

Has someone an idea what I've done wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating once jmsConnectionFactory. through your @Beans annotation
and second time instead of auto wiring it from jmsTemplate doing so:

```
@Bean
  public JmsTemplate JmsTemplate(ConnectionFactory jmsConnectionFactory) {
   // initialization code here
  }
```

You are creating it manually second time:

```
jmsTemplate.setConnectionFactory(jmsConnectionFactory());
```

Same goes for

```
jmsListenerContainerFactory
```

Do not create it several times, use injection instead.

UPDATE:
You can not have @Transactional annotation on private method. Put your annotation on the Public listener interface.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I've implement this but the error is the same

Comment: I've wrote a sample application with your hints and it works now. In my complex application not, but I think there's another problem, which causes the error